# Protractor/js end-to-end test stops execution before Promise, using async commands

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

The sense of below scenario is cache (remember) values of given elements of the table record on the main page, and after click on this records assert that on the second page the same content is displayed.

I assume that test finishing before the callback returns.

Scenario:

```
var Q = require('q');

module.exports = {

beforeEach: function (browser) {
    if (!browser.globals.isLocal) {
        var loginSite = browser.page.loginSite();
        loginSite.navigate();
        loginSite.logIn();
    }
    var welcomePage = browser.page.welcomePage();
    welcomePage.navigate();
    welcomePAge.waitForElementVisible('@usersButton', browser.globals.firstLoadWaitInMs)
        .click('@usersButton');
},
    afterEach: function (browser, done) {
        browser.end(function() {
            done();
        });
    },

    'should display same data on second page as on first page': function (browser) {
        //Given
        var firstPage = bowser.pages.first()
        //When
        Q.all([
            firstPage.getTextPromise('@element1'),
            firstPage.getTextPromise('@element2'),
            firstPage.getTextPromise('@element3')]
        ).then( function(values) {
            users.click('@linkToSecondPage');
            //Then
            var secondPage = browser.page.secondPage();
            secondPage.expect.element('@dataElement1').text.to.equal(values[0]).before(5000);
            secondPage.expect.element('@dataElemnet2').contains.text(values[1]);
            secondPage.expect.element('@dataElement3').contains.text(values[2]);
        });
    } }
```

The getTextPromise command is defined by me in following way:

```
commands: [{
    getTextPromise: function(selector) {
        var self = this;
        return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            self.getText(selector, function(result) {resolve(result.value); });
        });
    } }]
```

Tried as well to solve it with `async.series` library - I mean pack some steps into separate functions and run it sequentially but met problem that everything what is inside a function is local for this function so can't be invoked in the next one.

Comment: So your `values` array is empty when the second page expects run? Or is it that your second page expect statements are running even before the second page opens?

Comment: I think that nothing what is under `ar firstPage = bowser.pages.first()`  is  executed.  Meanwhile tried to `console.log(value[0])` but with none results.

Comment: @GirishSortur I think as well that it's not fault of `getTextPromise` method because it implements simple `getText` which is working normally. For example code like this works fine (means that return value in console.log):                                                                                  `var deferred = new Q.defer();    function getName() {        var name = userDetails.getText('@userDetailsFirstName', function (result) {            var name = result.value;            console.log(name);        });        deferred.resolve(name);   }`